# Significant performance hit after spawning dummy thread unrelated to task, in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am working on a C program to generate graphs to do with Ramsey Theory, and I'm currently refining my multithreading performance. At some point I decided to just do a sanity check and make sure that my multi-threaded implementation, when told to run with only 1 thread, is at least not slower than my original implementation.

It turns out it was running about 50% slower. A lot of trial and error later I managed to get it to the following state:

```
void * blah(){
   printf("Hello, this is thread\n");
}

void clean(){
   //Set up function

   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, blah, NULL);

   //Do computationally expensive stuff in the current thread
}
```

As shown above, the program takes 42 seconds with the first data set, and 767 with the other.
If I comment out the pthread_create call, the same exact program processes the first data set in 30 seconds and the second in 528 seconds.

I've tried looking for solutions and found a lot of great answers to do with false sharing and cache thrashing etc. When running the multithreaded version with 2, 3, or 4 threads I do see that each further thread runs a little slower, but what I cannot understand is why spawning even a single unrelated thread kills performance so much.

Even spawning a dozen copies of the same blah thread in this reduced case results in the exact same performance penalty. I even tried again without the -O3 compile flag and the same proportional slowdown was there, albeit a little less extreme. The only thing that might have to do with it that I haven't tried yet is to compile and run on a different system.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

After taking into account the suggestions from the comments, it appears I have found the problem. @ninjalj suggested that it might be to do with malloc locks, so I wrote the following test code that runs in 19 seconds without the call to pthread_create, and 32 seconds with it, at least on my machine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define CALLS 10000

void * dummy(void * args){
  printf("Hello, this is thread\n");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, dummy, NULL);

  time_t start, end;
  start = time(NULL);

  int * memory;
  for(int i = 0; i < CALLS*10; i ++){
    for(int j = 0; j < CALLS; j++){
      memory = malloc(10);
      free(memory);
    }
  }

  end = time(NULL);
  printf("That took %d s\n", end - start);
}
```

Comment: Give a minimal, verifiable and complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You know that a thread need resource too ? By the way, nice UB.

Comment: @klutt I will try and add a mcve tomorrow, because the current code is about 3k lines.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm aware that a thread needs resources too, but a) that thread should finish almost instantly and b) wouldn't the slowdown be the same no matter the input data size? Also I mentioned that the same slowdown occurs whether I spawn 1 blah thread or over a dozen of them.

Comment: It sounds as though spawning a thread triggers activity in the main thread that protects the main thread from possible concurrent activity, even if the actual concurrent activity is as near 'nothing' as reasonable.  It isn't clear that joining the dummy thread would reinstate the performance.  I've not proved that hypothesis (a grandiose term for a WAG — wild-a***d guess) in any way, but it might account for the trouble.  Does terminating the child thread properly (`return 0;`) make any difference (or accepting the argument)?  It probably won't, but you may as well avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does running the computationally expensive stuff in its own thread function — and in its own thread, therefore — make any difference?  It probably won't, but it would leave the main code doing the coordination while the child threads do their own thing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Joining to the dummy thread does nothing for performance, and neither does adding return 0; . You're absolutely right about that structure though, that is how I had it running originally, with the main thread launching some predefined number of threads. I rewrote it like this to try and isolate the cause of the slowdown. So no it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: No big surprise — they're not supposed to make a difference. Which platform are you running on (hardware, o/s, compiler)?  Does running the computation in a thread function without the companion dummy still show the slow-down?  The main thread would launch that and then wait in `pthread_join()`.  Under the circumstances, I think the answer should be "yes" — that is, when run in a thread, the computation should slow down.  But as to why, unless my 'the support software checks for multi-threading and behaves differently when it is detected' hypothesis is right, I'm not at all sure.

Comment: do you access `stdout` during the "computationally expensive stuff".  If so, I have a feeling that changing output pipe to `stderr` in `blah()` would speed things up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm running on Arch Linux, using gcc and an i5-3570k. Yes, if there's any thread spawned anywhere the slowdown occurs, whether it's one or 500 or whether the computation is in the main thread or the child thread.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Yes I do, for logging progress. Changing it to fprintf(stderr, "Hello, this is thread\n"); does nothing for speed.

Comment: Look at the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) support code, then.  I suspect that there is different behaviour based on 'only original thread' vs 'any child thread of any sort has been created'.  Things like having to call [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) before using any file stream (in functions like `printf()` or `fprintf()`) and 
`funlockfile()` before returning could slow things down. Does GCC 4.x vs 7.1 make any odds? I'd be quite surprised if the compiler matters, but …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can do you one better, I haven't tried the older gcc but I forgot that for my troubleshooting I don't actually use printf at all in the computationally expensive part, the only time it gets called, remotely near is in the dummy thread.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Same exact times for gcc5, so we can rule that out

Comment: Unless most of what your program does is logging, these numbers don't look reasonable at all. Try to disable all logging and see what happens.

Comment: @n.m. Those numbers in the OP are without any logging whatsoever.

Comment: The only thing I can think of (without seeing actual code that exhibits the problem) that could produce the symptoms described, is either inefficient code, or if the computationally heavy thread also allocates/reallocates/frees memory; with the thread stacks somehow causing worse data locality issues. Examining the `/proc/self/maps` in the two cases (slowdown vs. no slowdown), at the same points in the computation, and only looking at the data segments (`rw-p`, except for initialized data for shared libraries), might show if this is the case.

Comment: @NominalAnimal The example given in the OP does everything in the main thread, which does include some memory allocation and freeing. So what you're saying is the process of launching a new thread might screw with memory operation efficiency? Because right now I'm not really looking at algorithm inefficiencies, just relative performance with and without that dummy thread and why they're different.

Comment: I agree that this is very strange.  The thread does next-to-nothing, just one I/O system call, and could not make any difference in the order of seconds:(  Weird...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. In my experiments, a purely computational program doesn't experience any visible slowdown. A program that does lots of memory allocations may experience a slight slowdown while having lots of I/O makes it worse (still not the extreme figures you report).

Comment: Note that the signature of blah() is incorrect for a pthread.

Comment: If we assume it is not an implementation issue in your code (interactions with the spawned thread), there are not many things that could have such an impact; data locality *could* in theory account for some of it. I cannot reproduce it myself either, as the worst slowdowns due to e.g. using fixed memory maps with large addresses have been on the order of 10%. Essentially, I believe it is some kind of accidental sillyness in your code, while keeping the door minimally open for some really weird memory interaction slowdown or kernel bug.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Fixing the signature doesn't change anything.

Comment: @NominalAnimal  Yeah, I just have no explanation for this either.  pthread_create() may well perform no C malloc calls at all, (though I've not looked at it's code), and the thread stack allocation would surely be provided by the underlying OS kernel, not the C 'malloc' heap sub-allocator.  This has to be something silly...

Comment: @DarioGonzalez I didn't think it would.  I had to mention it though:)

Comment: My only guess would be UB in the 'setup function' and/or the 'computationally expensive stuff', with the pthread_create() call changing the flavour of UB.

Comment: @DarioGonzalez: Are you comparing wall-clock time, CPU time, or both?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: regarding flockfile(), I don't think glibc does anything special for single-threaded programs at the moment, since there is a patch "single-threaded stdio optimization" doing the rounds in glibc-alpha at the moment to do just that, at least for some functions. My take is that malloc/free are more likely to be the culprit (there's another patch by DJ Delorie "malloc per-thread cache" also on glibc-alpha ATM).

Comment: @DarioGonzalez: We probably need a better explanation of your malloc()/free() usage.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: It may be that single-threaded programs avoid taking locks in malloc()/free().

Comment: I'm using clock(), which is in turn wall clock time. I'm calling malloc and free several hundred thousand times over the course of the computationally expensive, though that's only a rough guess. If ninjalj is right that might explain it, though the only way to make sure would be to do a lot of mallocs and frees with and without a thread running and see if there is ant difference.

Comment: I just wrote a simple test program, which does some double-precision calculations in a `void *work(void *payload)` function. On a Core i5-4200U (dual-core Haswell) laptop, a certain set of calculations takes 1.06 seconds real time and 1.06 seconds CPU time using a single thread, but 0.37 seconds real time and 1.44 seconds CPU time (summed CPU time over all threads); measured over the computations only.

Comment: @DarioGonzalez: No, [`clock()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) returns CPU time (total CPU time used by all threads in the process, similar to `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`), not wall clock time. Issue solved: misinterpreted timing measurements! You should use POSIX.1 `clock_gettime()`, anyway.

Comment: Sorry not clock(), time(). It definitely takes longer real time too, though I haven't checked with a watch.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Also why would calling printf once increase the CPU time by 50%?

Comment: @DarioGonzalez: You're not being precise. Above, you claim that it is creating the (second) thread that increases the time; now, you claim it is the `printf()` call. No, I believe the true reason is in your code, that it does something silly. You really need to show a test case we can run and verify. As I mentioned above, I cannot reproduce your results, even with a test program where the single-threaded version neither includes `pthread.h` nor links against pthread. If you wish to find out the answer to this question, we need code we can run, test, verify, and examine.

Comment: @NominalAnimal No you're right I'm referring to the printf inside that thread. My last question was why enabling that thread, which consists of a single printf, would increase the required cpu time by 50%, in a program that takes several minutes to run. I will update tomorrow with all the suggestions so far plus some sample code.

Comment: Use `time` *command*.